# SQL Server Scalar UDF Parallelism Mystery!

Tags: sql-server, parallelism, check-constraints, computed-column

Referencing [this blog post](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/04/another-hidden-parallelism-killer-scalar-udfs-check-constraints/) by Erik Darling on the website of my favorite SQL Server guru - Brent Ozar:

When you **select from that table alone**, it shows "**CouldNotGenerateValidParallelPlan**".

But, **when you join that table to another** that does not have a check constraint/computed column calling a Scalar UDF, the query goes parallel with "**Good Enough Plan Found**"

```
USE tempdb;
SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT TOP 10000
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY ( SELECT NULL )) AS ID, DATEADD(MINUTE, m.message_id, SYSDATETIME()) AS SomeDate
INTO   dbo.constraint_test_1
FROM   sys.messages AS m, sys.messages AS m2;
GO

SELECT TOP 10000
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY ( SELECT NULL )) AS ID, DATEADD(MINUTE, m.message_id, SYSDATETIME()) AS SomeDate
INTO   dbo.constraint_test_2
FROM   sys.messages AS m, sys.messages AS m2;
GO

CREATE  FUNCTION dbo.DateCheck ( @d DATETIME2(7))
RETURNS BIT
WITH    RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @Out BIT;
        SELECT  @Out = CASE WHEN @d < DATEADD(DAY, 30, SYSDATETIME()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
        RETURN  @Out;
    END;
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.constraint_test_1 ADD CONSTRAINT ck_cc_dt CHECK ( dbo.DateCheck(SomeDate) = 1 );

SELECT  *
FROM    dbo.constraint_test_1
OPTION  (QUERYTRACEON 8649, MAXDOP 0, RECOMPILE); -- Does not go parallel

SELECT  T1.ID, T2.SomeDate
FROM    dbo.constraint_test_1 T1 INNER JOIN
        dbo.constraint_test_2 T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
OPTION  (QUERYTRACEON 8649, MAXDOP 0, RECOMPILE); -- Goes parallel
```

Comment: Added some more information to my answer to address your comments

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need a *non-trivial* plan if you want parallelism, plus the optimizer must be able to find a valid parallel plan for the query.

For example, modifying your first query (which did not use parallelism):

```
SELECT  COUNT_BIG(*)
FROM    dbo.constraint_test_1
WHERE   ID > (SELECT 0)
OPTION  (QUERYTRACEON 8649, MAXDOP 0, RECOMPILE); -- Goes parallel
```

[image: parallel]

I changed the `SELECT *` to `SELECT COUNT_BIG(*)` there to avoid projecting the column with the scalar UDF constraint. I also added a `WHERE` clause complex enough to skip the trivial plan stage.

Your second query (which *did* go parallel) can be modified to be always serial due to the constraint:

```
SELECT  T1.ID, T2.SomeDate, T1.SomeDate
FROM    dbo.constraint_test_1 T1 INNER JOIN
        dbo.constraint_test_2 T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
OPTION  (QUERYTRACEON 8649, MAXDOP 0, RECOMPILE); -- No parallel
```

[image: not parallel]

I added *T1.SomeDate* to the projection list, so the problematic column is now used by the query. When the column is not needed, the constraint on it is disregarded by the optimizer, so it can find a parallel plan.

The *NonParallelPlanReason* [show plan attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/query-processing-architecture-guide#parallel-query-processing) may be added early in compilation when the process detects a condition that would prevent parallelism. For example, the following query produces the reason *ParallelismDisabledByTraceFlag*:

```
SELECT CT.ID 
FROM dbo.constraint_test_1 AS CT 
OPTION (QUERYTRACEON 8687);
```

The presence of a non-parallel reason does *not* mean parallelism would definitely have been considered otherwise. The optimizer only considers parallelism after the trivial plan stage, optionally *search 0*, and definitely *search 1*. For more information on optimizer stages please see my [Query Optimizer Deep Dive](https://www.sql.kiwi/2012/04/query-optimizer-deep-dive-part-1.html) series.

You mentioned in a comment that you are interested in the behaviour of computed columns referencing scalar functions with parallelism. I describe this in [Properly Persisted Computed Columns](https://sqlperformance.com/2017/05/sql-plan/properly-persisted-computed-columns).

Finally, not a particular concern here, but if you want to test things like this you're better off doing it in a real user database not *tempdb*. There are several things that work differently in *tempdb*.